# Problema mySQL PHP ao usar o trema

Tags: php, mysql, acentuação

Preciso desenvolver um script que verifique se há caractere acentuado com trema na string e guarde uma variável da string sem o trema.

O script que listo abaixo compila

```
//Checa Especial
$nomeCliente = "Bröring";

if(strstr($nomeCliente, "ä") || 
   strstr($nomeCliente, "ö") || 
   strstr($nomeCliente, "ü")){

    if(strstr($nomeCliente, "ä")){ $variavel .= str_replace("ä", "a", $nomeCliente).","; }
    if(strstr($nomeCliente, "ö")){ $variavel .= str_replace("ö", "o", $nomeCliente).","; }
    if(strstr($nomeCliente, "ü")){ $variavel .= str_replace("ü", "u", $nomeCliente).","; }

    echo $variavel;
    //Imprime Broring,

}else{
    echo "Não há trema";
}
```

Fiz uma query direto no PHPmyAdmin

```
SELECT id, nome FROM clientes WHERE nome LIKE '%ö%'
```

Pra ver se poderia puxar os dados assim e compila
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então implementei um script

```
//Gera variáveis do nome
$sqlTremas = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, nome FROM clientes WHERE nome LIKE '%ö%' OR nome LIKE '%ä%' OR nome LIKE '%ü%'");

while($dadosT = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlTremas)) {
    //Checa Especial
    $nomeCliente = utf8_decode($nomeCliente);

    if(strstr($nomeCliente, "ä")){ $variavel .= str_replace("ä", "a", $nomeCliente).","; }
    if(strstr($nomeCliente, "ö")){ $variavel .= str_replace("ö", "o", $nomeCliente).","; }
    if(strstr($nomeCliente, "ü")){ $variavel .= str_replace("ü", "u", $nomeCliente).","; }

    $tamanhoStringVariavel = strlen($variavel);
    $variavel = substr($variavel, 0, $tamanhoStringVariavel-1);

    $alteraCliente = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE clientes SET variavel = '{$variavel}' WHERE id = {$dadosT['id']}");

    if($alteraCliente) {
        echo "SUCESSO {$dadosT['id']}<br><br>";
    }else{
        echo "ERRO {$dadosT['id']}<br><br>";
    }
}
```

Nesse código o `mysql_num_rows($sqlTremas)` vem vazio, mas quando compilo direto no mysql, funciona. Tenho outra query no mesmo arquivo que funciona (não é conexão com o banco de dados). O que pode ser?

Comment: De curiosidade, qual o problema de ter trema na string do DB? Não seria melhor simplesmente manter como está, e acertar a collation e o charset do banco para que funcione tudo independentemente da acentuação?

Comment: Oi @Bacco, nenhum. Eu mantenho o trema no banco normalmente, mas numa busca desse projeto preciso que o cliente encontre o resultado se escrever o Bröring ou Broring, por exemplo.

Comment: Possivelmente no insert você utiliza utf8_encode e na comparação você decodifica string com uf8_decode como em utf8 os caracteres são salvos encodificados seu sql não ira funcionar.

Comment: Mas esse é o normal. Se não está encontrando, o problema é configuração errada. Usando o charset correto, e o collation swedish, JOÃO == joao. O que precisa ver é se quer compativel ou básico, o que pode transformar  "ö" em "oe" ou em apenas "o". Inclusive, Bröring é o mesmo que Broering, em princípio. Seja uma forma ou outra, a solução está no _collation_ do banco. Isto que foi buscado na pergunta é meio que "remendar" a coisa. Eu sugeriria tentar resolver direto no banco, sem alterar a string.

Comment: @Bacco estou usando colation latin1_swedish_ci, sem o trema o like não encontra o resultado direto no sql do phpmyAdmin. Devo utilizar outro?

Comment: se for latin1, tem que ser charset latin1. se quer utf8 no charset, use um collation utf8 também. Esta mistura pode ser a causa do problema.

Comment: @Bacco uma duvida besta: alterar o colation no banco pode alterar de alguma forma meus registros? Outra dúvida: o lance do joao e joão funciona. Quero dizer, dos acentos é só o trema o problema. Não é esquisito? Por isso imaginei que o problema era com o trema mesmo.

Comment: Sempre trabalhe com uma cópia. Alterar os seus dados originais pode dar a maior confusão, se não tiver prática com collation. Depois fica difícil consertar, pois pode misturar dados antigos em um formato e dados novos em outro. Sugiro que você tente alterar, mas só depois de garantir que pode voltar atrás se comenter algum equívoco. Sobre o trema, teste como comentei, veja se acha "broering" tendo "bröring" no banco. Se for isso, pode trocar pelo internacional mais simples, que não altera os _umlauts_

Comment: Relacionado :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzK6VdK8YRs

Answer (score 0):

Já verificou o trecho abaixo do comentário `*//Checa Especial*`

```
$sqlTremas = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, nome FROM clientes WHERE nome LIKE '%ö%' OR nome LIKE '%ä%' OR nome LIKE '%ü%'");

while ($dadosT = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlTremas)) {
    //Checa Especial
    $nomeCliente = ($dadosT['nome']);

    if (strstr($nomeCliente, "ä")) {
        $variavel .= str_replace("ä", "a", $nomeCliente) . ",";
    }
    if (strstr($nomeCliente, "ö")) {
        $variavel .= str_replace("ö", "o", $nomeCliente) . ",";
    }
    if (strstr($nomeCliente, "ü")) {
        $variavel .= str_replace("ü", "u", $nomeCliente) . ",";
    }

    $tamanhoStringVariavel = strlen($variavel);
    $variavel = substr($variavel, 0, $tamanhoStringVariavel - 1);

    $alteraCliente = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE clientes SET variavel = '{$variavel}' WHERE id = {$dadosT['id']}");

    if ($alteraCliente) {
        echo "SUCESSO {$dadosT['id']}<br><br>";
    } else {
        echo "ERRO {$dadosT['id']}<br><br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ele nem entra ali, pq não tem retorno na query via PHP. Mas se a minha query no PHP for '%o%' OR nome LIKE '%a%' OR nome LIKE '%u%' compila.